# Instance Show for function

Tags: haskell

I'm currently trying to write a little Show instance for primitive arithmetic functions.

Goal ist to make a list of functions showable.

The very simple function for show looks like that:

```
  showOp :: (Int -> Int -> Int) -> String
  showOp op
    | op 3 3 == 6 = "plus"
    | op 3 3 == 0 = "minus"
    | op 3 3 == 9 = "times"
    | op 3 3 == 1 = "divide"
    | otherwise = "undefined"
```

But I can't get an instance of Show for (Int -> Int -> Int). I tried it like that:

```
    instance Show (Int -> Int -> Int) where
    show op = show "asdf"
```

But it doesn't work. WinHugs just returns the Error

```
    Syntax error in instance head (variable expected)
```

Is it even possible to define Show for functions? If it is, how could I tackle that problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use WinHugs. Use GHC.

In fact, in recent Haskell Platform versions there is already an instance of functions for Show.

```
Prelude Text.Show.Functions> show (+1)
"<function>"
Prelude Text.Show.Functions> show (\x -> x ++ "foo")
"<function>"
```

Now, in your case, however, you need `-XFlexibleInstances` on, since your instance isn't of the form `(Constructor a1 .. an)` where a1 .. an are distinct type variables.

Turn it on with `{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}`

Comment: That said, it's not possible to define `Show` to actually give you more detail about the function.

Comment: Sure it is. It can show the type (given via Typeable); or it can show some of the inputs and outputs (as is done in QuickCheck).

Comment: ...Yes.  Okay.  Sorry.  It can't, however, show the implementation, or the name.

Answer (score 3):

(This isn't an answer (Don's covers it), but it is far too long for a comment)

The code has a lot of repeated logic (specifically `op 3 3 ==` occurs a lot), but there is away to make this cleaner: [case expressions](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions#case-expressions). This allows us to compute `op 3 3` once, and then handle the various cases (exactly the same as pattern matching in function definitions).

```
showOp op = case op 3 3 of
              6 -> "plus"
              0 -> "minus"
              9 -> "times"
              1 -> "divide"
              _ -> "undefined"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Hugs.

Start Hugs with `hugs -98 +o` or `runhugs -X-98 +o` and use `{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}` in your source file.