# Syntax error in instance head (variable expected)

Tags: haskell

I'm reading the book "The Haskell Road to Logic, Math and Programming" and I download their code from the second chapter(http://homepages.cwi.nl/~jve/HR/), but when I try to compile the code, it doesn't work.

The error message is:

```
TAMO.hs:85 - Syntax error in instance head (variable expected)
```

What variable is expected? I've never used Haskell before and have no idea what the compiler(Hugs) want me to do to fix it.

```
class TF p where 
  valid :: p -> Bool
  lequiv :: p -> p -> Bool
instance TF Bool
  where
  valid  = id
  lequiv f g = f == g

instance TF p => TF (Bool -> p)
  where
  valid f = valid (f True) && valid (f False)
  lequiv f g = (f True) `lequiv` (g True)
           && (f False) `lequiv` (g False)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It compiled for me, but I had to fix the indentation (`lequiv` needed to be at the same level as valid), and add the `FlexibleInstances` language extension using

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
```

(I am using GHC, I am not sure what the equivalent for HUGS is)

---

Additional info:

The last answer in [Instance Show for function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10551210/instance-show-for-function) shows you how to use `FlexibleInstances` in Hugs.

Comment: Sorry, but I meant the number "85" was the line 85.

Comment: Thank you, I'll be using GHC from now on